# Не работает код, возврат функции, C++

Tags: c++, функции

При компиляции открывается консоль, которая выводит два отрицательных восьмизначных числа. Что не так?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

pair<int, int> sumdif(int a, int b){

    return pair<int, int>(a + b, a - b);

}

int main() {

    int a = 5;
    int b = 7;
    int c, d;

    pair <int, int>(c,d)  = sumdif(a, b);
    cout << c << endl << d;
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: `pair <int, int>p  = ...`

Comment: `std::tie(c,d)  = sumdif(a, b);` если уж очень сильно хочется

Answer (score 6):

```
pair <int, int>(c,d)  = sumdif(a, b);
```

Тут у вас создана временная пара, которая получила значение и тут же потеряна...

Вот варианты:

```
auto p = sumdif(a, b);
cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;
```

Для С++17 можно так:

```
auto [c,d]  = sumdif(a, b);
cout << c << " " << d << endl;;
```

Экзотика с вашей парой - вывод только одного поля:

```
cout << (pair<int,int>(c,d) = sumdif(a, b)).first;
```